# Does this look like overfitting or something else?

Tags: neural-networks, overfitting

The input are a timeseries of 1x41x41 geospatial images (so, 5x1x41x41 for example). I managed to achieve an MSE of 0.53 with PCA and Random Forest. But I thought to use ConvLSTM since my input size is large and knowing that I can manipulate many variables to prevent overfitting.But as you can see from the image below, I'm having a hard time. My current model is as follows:

```
model = Sequential(
ConvLSTM(INPUT_DIM=1, 128, KERNEL_SIZE=[3,3], NUM_LAYERS=1, batch_first=True, bias=True, return_all_layers=False),
#torch.nn.BatchNorm3d(5),
torch.nn.MaxPool3d((8,8,8)),
torch.nn.ReLU(),
torch.nn.Flatten(),
torch.nn.Dropout(p=0.2),
torch.nn.Linear(2000,20)).to(DEVICE)
```

Before, the training loss would start similar to validation loss but keep on decreasing while the valid loss stays constant or increases, so I thought of data augmentation and added the following transform functions to my training loader:

```
class CustomDataset(torch.utils.data.Dataset):
def __init__(self, inputs, labels, transform=True, target_transform=None):
    self.inputs = inputs
    self.labels = labels
    self.transform = transform
    self.target_transform = target_transform

def __len__(self):
    return len(self.labels)

def __getitem__(self, idx):
    image = self.inputs[idx]
    label = self.labels[idx]
    if self.transform:
        r = np.random.choice([0,1,2,3,4])
        if r == 2:
            image = np.flip(image, axis=(2)).copy()
        elif r == 3:
            image = np.flip(image, axis=(3)).copy()
        elif r == 4:
            image = np.flip(image, axis=(2,3)).copy()
    image = torch.tensor(image)
    label = torch.tensor(label)
    return image.to(DEVICE), label.to(DEVICE)
```

That might explain why my training loss starts higher than my valid loss since I'm not applying such transformations for the latter. Training batch size is 32 and validation batch size is 1. I'm normalizing my input values as follows:

```
X = zscore(np.array(X).reshape(5599,5,1,41,41))
```

I'm using adam with lr=1e-3. Any suggestions? Is my reasoning flawed? Thanks in advance.

[image: Training vs Validation loss]

Comment: "That might explain why my training loss starts higher than my valid loss since I'm not applying such transformations for the latter." Without understanding any detail of your code, training and validation loss cannot be compared if based on different versions of the data such as transformed/untransformed.

Comment: I've written my transform code. It just flips the images. I'm not applying the same on the valid set(transform is set to false) . The original dataset is split 80/20 as train/valid using sklearn's split function. Is that wrong?